# Do something if "?something" is present at the end of a URL

Tags: php, url

I want to make it so that if there is a `?no` at the end of a url, then something does not happen. But, if there is nothing at the end of the url, then something does happen. How can I do this?

Comment: Could You share your code?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['no'])) {
//something happen
} else {
//do nothing

}
```

Comment: That pretty much sums it up.